# Where is Wine's "skeleton" for ~/.wine?

Tags: linux, wine

I am building an application that will run on Linux under Wine, and I'd like to add a few files to the default windows image that is created in ~/.wine when a user starts wine for the first time - kind of like /etc/skel that's used to create new users.

Is there a way to do this? I can't seem to find how ~/.wine is created.

Also, is there a way to import a registry key using regedit at the same time (i.e. when a user starts wine for the first time)?

NOTE: this is on RHEL/Centos 5 using EPEL wine RPM's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `/usr/share/wine/wine.inf`.

Comment: Hmmm... doesn't seem to allow plugging in additional .inf's? (Kind of like xinetd or /etc/cron.d do). Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only way to change the default is to modify that file.  If you just want to set up your own independent .wine for your one application, you could write a script that copies it from wherever you want, then sets `$WINEPREFIX` to point to that directory while your app is running.